# Rake test fails with LoadError, looking in home directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, osx-lion, rake-test

When I try to run "rake test" on my newly generated rails application I receive the following error

```
Computer:heroku user$ rake test:units
/Users/user
file doesnt exist
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require': cannot load such file -- /Users/user/test/unit/helpers/things_helper_test.rb (LoadError)
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:10:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:9:in `each'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:9:in `block in <main>'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:4:in `select'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:4:in `<main>'
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/b...]

Tasks: TOP => test:units
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I am guessing that this is related to my setup somehow, as it seems as if rake is looking for the generated files in my home directory instead of the rails application directory. Could you help direct me to what I am doing wrong?

I am using Mac OS X Lion, have two installed ruby versions (1.8.7 come with lion, 1.9.3 which I am using for the application has been installed using rvm).

The application works if I run "rails s".

Update: If I create a new rails application from scratch, adding only a generated scaffold, the rake test command works. Ergo, it might be a incompatibility issue as the failing rails application was created on another computer, uploaded to heroku and then cloned from there to a new computer.

Comment: Just to be sure, where did you execute `rake test:unites`? From what you posted above, it looks like `/User/user`?

Comment: I executed the command in the /Users/user/Workspace/heroku directory, which is the top directory of the rails application

Comment: I suspect that there is something wrong with the Rakefile.

Comment: Hmm, besides a require rake:dsl line there is no difference between the Rakefile of a new, working, application and the above that doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funny story. I'd accidentally put some test code in one of the files, among other containing:

```
Dir.chdir("../..")
```

I'm guessing that when I run `rake test` the file got executed to load the class contained in the file, and caused problems when looking for the next file, when the current directory had suddenly changed.